# Always redirect http to https

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect, https

This is the code I have so far:

```
<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    ReWriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} !^443$
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NC,R,L]
</IfModule>
```

Ideally I am trying to achieve a situation where any request to:

```
http://domain.com/
```

and/or

```
http://www.domain.com/
```

is redirected to

```
https://domain.com/whatever/sub/directory
```

So far the attempts I have made only redirect the root domain to the HTTPS, when I go into some sub directory of the site and remove the HTTPS from the URL, it doesn't redirect it back to the HTTPS, it just stays on HTTP.

I am a major newbie at htaccess so any advice is appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22208857/htaccess-wordpress-vanity-urls#comment33718340_22208857

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't really answer my question.

Comment: It is a _start_ to fixing your problem though.

Comment: That's true. I've taken it into account and are trying stuff out with it.

Comment: @Ollie Is this solved for you?

Answer (score 0):

Remove leading slash:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [NE,R=301,L]
```

- `.htaccess` is per directory directive and Apache strips the current directory path (thus leading slash) from `RewriteRule` URI pattern.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If you go to my site https://gearhub.co.uk/about-gearhub/terms-and-conditions/ and then remove the 'https' or replace it with 'http' you can see that it goes to http and doesn't redirect to https.

Comment: Just make sure this rule is very first rule in your root .htacess and .htaccess is indeed enabled.

Answer (score 0):

If the ssl.conf file does not exist, you may have to install the mod_ssl module
If the file - /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf exists, comment out everything in it from the  header to the  header including the headers themselves.

Make sure the "LoadModule ssl_module modules/mod_ssl.so" directive is present and not commented out in the file. Otherwise add it.

Modify the /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file. Add the following part to the end -

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName www.example.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
Redirect permanent / https://www.example.com/
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName www.example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /var/cert/abcd344.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /var/cert/www_example_com.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /var/cert/gd_bundle-g2-g1.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

The above settings will redirect all requests to port 443 (HTTPS).